# Programatically add simple to configurable products

Tags: magento-enterprise, attributes, configurable-product, simple-product, ee-1.11

I have configurable products that have simple products and they are configurable by two attributes - posters with size and frame.
I am adding new products that represent new frames and sizes which are created ok, but I want them to attach to a certain configurable product.

Example:
I have a configurable product - poster with this simple products

```
Wood frame - 30x30cm
Aluminum frame - 50x50cm
Aluminum frame - 70x50cm
```

I generate

```
Wood 50 x 50cm
Aluminum 100x100cm
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @marius. I got a answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287407/attach-simple-products-to-a-configurable-product-programmatically).

You can assign simple product to configurable by following code

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable') ->saveProducts($mainConfigrableProduct, $simpleProductIds);
```

Here `$mainConfigrableProduct` is configurable product object and `$simpleProductIds` is array of simple product id